# jQuery Ajax does NOT continue onto any of the callbacks .done, .fail, .always - Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

Basic example where i deliberately put a fake URL that does not exist.

```
$.ajax({
    url     : 'https://google.com/404', 
    dataType: 'html', 
    cache   : false, 
    done : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        console.log('data:',data);
        console.log('textStatus:', textStatus);
        console.log('jqXHR:', jqXHR);
    },
    fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('jqXhr:',jqXHR);
        console.error('textStatus:', textStatus);
        console.error('errorThrown:', errorThrown);
    },
    always: function( data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown ) { 
        console.warn('data_jqXHR:',data_jqXHR);
        console.warn('textStatus:', textStatus);
        console.warn('jqXHR_errorThrown:', jqXHR_errorThrown);
    }
}); //end-ajax
```

I would have expected it to take the .fail path, and then the .always path, but it does neither, except for the console which shows an error:

> GET 'https://google.com/404' 404

How can I get jQuery or javascript to throw a 404 ? e.g. alert('404 error')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [the right syntax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://google.com/404',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert("done");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("failed");
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert("always");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I used the old syntax with .success, error, complete BUT replaced it with their equivalent counterparts, but obviously it's not possible. Incidentally your modern syntax does indeed reject into fail() and always() BUT the fact that the error is a 404 is nowhere to be found within respective callbacks.